# Why does rvalue object does not get moved to function with rvalue parameter?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I was wondering why `std::move` to a function with an rvalue parameter was not actually moving anything, but passing by reference instead?

Especially when I know it works for constructors.

I was running the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void consume_ptr(std::shared_ptr<int> && ptr) {
    std::cout << "Consumed " << (void*) ptr.get() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>();
    consume_ptr(std::move(ptr));
    if (ptr) {
        std::cout << "ptr should be moved?" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
ptr should be moved?
```

According to everything I've read, the `std::shared_ptr` should have been moved inside the function, meaning that the object `ptr` itself would hold `nullptr` after moving it into `consume_ptr`, but it doesn't!

I tried it with some custom class of mine with logging, and it looks like the move constructor is never even called.
It's reproducible under every compiler and optimization level.

Can anyone clear this up for me please?

Comment: _I tried it with some custom class of mine with logging_ OK, please show the class.

Comment: Wrapping something in `std::move` does not cause it to be moved from. It signals to the compiler that the object may be moved from and to call the appropriate function (if it can be found). It us up to your function to actually consume it, if that's what you want it to do. `ptr.get()` does not modify `ptr` at all.

Comment: `std::move` is just a cast - it doesn't move anything, and your call is equivalent to `consume_ptr(static_cast<std::shared_ptr<int>&&>(ptr))`. It just makes it *possible* for someone to nick the contents of the object.

Comment: @JHBonarius https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D states clearly that the moved object remains empty – where's the UB?

Comment: Create another shared pointer inside your function and assign the rvalue reference to – then you should see the change you expect...

Comment: @JohnFilleau  Yeah, I think I made a booboo. You're right. Still, it's use-after-move. The object might be anything.

Comment: Remove the `&&` from the function's parameter and see what happens.

Comment: @Aconcague assignment? Why is that used? if anything the move constructor is used, right?

Comment: @JHBonarius "the object might be anything" is true for move operations in general, but a given move operation may specify exact behavior. This is the case for `shared_ptr`. Even the humble `std::vector` has a well defined state after being moved from: size shall be 0.

Comment: Although objects of some types may remain valid after move, I think the more important thing is to avoid use-after-move in general, even if it doesn't actually result in UB, just for good practice.

Comment: @JHBonarius We need a move construction of or assignment to another concrete object, not a reference, to see moving actually occurring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::move` by itself does not actually move anything. That is to say, `std::move` alone does not invoke any move constructors or move-assignment operators. What it actually does is effectively cast its argument into an rvalue as if by `static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)`, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

In order for any moving to actually happen, the moved object must be assigned to or used in the move-initialization of something else. For example, it could be used to initialize a member.

```cpp
void something::consume_ptr(std::shared_ptr<int> && ptr) {
    this->ptr = std::move(ptr);
    std::cout << "Consumed " << (void*) ptr.get() << std::endl;
}
```

However, one way to make your pointer get moved without being assigned to anything is to simply pass it by value, causing your pointer to be moved into the parameter.

```cpp
void consume_ptr(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr) {
    std::cout << "Consumed " << (void*) ptr.get() << std::endl;
}
```

This way can actually be more useful than the rvalue way if you're going to end up assigning the parameter to something, because it allows you to pass stuff in by copy, too, and not just by move.

```cpp
void consume_ptr_by_rvalue(std::shared_ptr<int> && ptr);
void consume_ptr_by_value(std::shared_ptr<int> ptr);

void do_stuff() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> x = /*...*/;
    std::shared_ptr<int> y = /*...*/;

    // consume_ptr_by_rvalue(x); // Doesn't work
    consume_ptr_by_rvalue(std::move(y)); // Risk of use-after-move

    std::shared_ptr<int> z = /*...*/;
    std::shared_ptr<int> w = /*...*/;

    consume_ptr_by_value(z);
    consume_ptr_by_value(std::move(w)); // Still risk, but you get the idea
    consume_ptr_by_value(make_shared_ptr_to_something()); // Can directly pass result of something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
void consume_ptr( std::shared_ptr<int>&& ptr )
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> new_ptr { ptr }; // calling copy ctor

    std::cout << "Consumed " << ( void* ) new_ptr.get( ) << '\n';
}
```

No move happens there. No call to a move ctor or a move assignment operator. That's just a simple pass by rvalue reference there.

**Output:**

```
Consumed 0x20d77ebe6a0
ptr should be moved?
```

Now take a look at this:

```
void consume_ptr( std::shared_ptr<int>&& ptr )
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> new_ptr { std::move(ptr) }; // calling move ctor

    std::cout << "Consumed " << ( void* ) new_ptr.get( ) << '\n';
}

int main( )
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr { std::make_shared<int>( ) };
    consume_ptr( std::move(ptr) );

    if ( ptr )
    {
        std::cout << "ptr should be moved?" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Consumed 0x21160bbdf40
```

See. The move operation happened. And the `if`'s body did not run.